# How to put multiple user inputs into a dictionary and then print in numerical order

Tags: python

I am extremely new to code and I need to finish a project for school where I write a code for an imaginary surfing competition that takes user inputed names and scores and then prints them in order from highest to lowest score using a dictionary
Ex:
Tim: 32
Dave:12
Gabe:2

This is what I have so far

```
surf_list ={}
print("What are the names of the surfers?")
name = input("surfer: ")
score = input("score: ")
surf_list[name] = score
```

Can anyone point me in a better direction to ace this project??

Comment: You need to use a while loop. And an if condition to break.

Comment: do you have any examples of this, I am extremely new and haven't spent much time working with those

Comment: One way to do it: Step 1: loop thru to accept all values. Step 2: Store all the inputs into a list as tuples (name,score). Step 3: Once you have all the values entered, sort the list in highest to lowest. Step 4: Print the list.  If the users have unique names, you can store into a dict as name:score

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
n = int(input("Please enter number of surfers"))
surf_list ={}
print("What are the names of the surfers?")
for i in range(n):
    name = input("surfer: ")
    score = int(input("score: "))
    surf_list[name] = score
    #sort dictionary based on scores
res = {k: v for k, v in sorted(surf_list.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
for i,j in res.items():
    print("Name:",i,"Score:",j)
```

Another method using while loop. Here instead of pre-defining number of surfers, you can stop in between the loop

```
is_another_surfer = True 

surf_list ={}
print("What are the names of the surfers?")
while is_another_surfer:
    name = input("surfer: ")
    score = int(input("score: "))
    surf_list[name] = score
    #sort dictionary based on scores
    has_another = input("Do you want to add another surfer. Press Y or N")
    if has_another.lower() == 'n':
        is_another_surfer = False

res = {k: v for k, v in sorted(surf_list.items(), key=lambda item: item[1])}
for i,j in res.items():
    print("Name:",i,"Score:",j)
```

Comment: you will need to get the name and score in a loop

Comment: Edited and  I checked by compiling the code

Comment: Since scores are stored as strings, 11 will be ahead of 9. Try to address for it as well

Comment: @SAISANTOSHCHIRAG Could you add another option with a while loop that asks if there is another surfer to add, and confirm with a [Y/n] question?

Comment: set is_another_surfer to True. You havent initialized before it gets to first while statement

Comment: It was just an indentation problem

Answer (score 0):

your code has  to change slightly
find the below code for reference

```
class my_dictionary(dict): 
  
    # __init__ function 
    def __init__(self): 
        self = dict() 
          
    # Function to add key:value 
    def add(self, key, value): 
        self[key] = value 
  
#  Class instance
print("What are the names of the surfers?")
dict_obj = my_dictionary() 

while True:
    
    name = input("enter name: ")
    score = int(input("enter score: "))
    dict_obj.add(name,score) 
    for k in sorted(dict_obj, key=dict_obj.get, reverse=True):
        print(k,":",dict_obj[k])
```